# how to edit css inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a logo in my website, when the user opens my website the logo is big, but when he scrolls it becomes small. i did that using javascript like below

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    growShrinkLogo()
  };

  function growShrinkLogo() {
    var Logo = document.getElementById("logo")
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 5) {
      Logo.style.width = '80px';
    } else {
      Logo.style.width = '200px';
    }
  }
```

```html
<div   class="logo">
        <div class="relative-logo">
          <img id="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
      </div>
```

the first logo which appears is a littile bit right towards the page and the second is properly in the center, like below images

[image]

[image]

when i am trying to move the bigger logo it is effecting the small logo because both of it is in the same div. how can i make the bigger logo which appears when the page load to the center without effecting the smaller logo. can anyone help

Comment: margin:auto  might help?

Comment: Where is the other logo?

Comment: @mplungjan but both the logos are in same div

Comment: @Adriani6 both are one logo, just used js to make it big and small

Comment: Like this: `.logo { width:100%; text-align:center }
#logo {margin:auto}`

Comment: @mplungjan not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  growShrinkLogo();
};

function growShrinkLogo() {
  var Logo = document.getElementById("logo");

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 5) {
    Logo.style.width = '80px';
    Logo.style.marginLeft = '60px';
  } else {
    Logo.style.width = '200px';
    Logo.style.marginLeft = '0px';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="relative-logo">
    <img id="logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This will work if you haven't already defined a margin in your CSS and used position instead. I think..... try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put script before close body tag? I tried your code, it still change width?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  growShrinkLogo()
};

function growShrinkLogo() {
  var Logo = document.getElementById("logo")
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 5) {
    Logo.style.width = '80px';
  } else {
    Logo.style.width = '200px';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="relative-logo">
    <img id="logo" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19644.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: i didnt understand what you said

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving this.

- Use two different HTML elements (two logos) and then hide/show them, similar to how you're changing the CSS of a single element. That way you can modify each logo's CSS independently.
- Change the CSS of your main logo for page load, and then fix it back with JavaScript (basically, remove whatever you added for the big one)

Update:

After re-reading your question I think I understand.

Try adding this to your CSS (update according to your needs):

```
.relative-logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

That should center align both of your logos and make them stay centered regardless of their size.

Comment: @ZubairShah I updated my answer, I think I understand what you need now.

Comment: but the width is not increasing, as i want

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment. Your question is `how can i make the bigger logo which appears when the page load to the center without effecting the smaller logo`.

You never mentioned width not increasing.

Comment: the width is increasing in my javascript

Comment: but when i am using your code, the width is not increasing, its jist slight bigger than my smaller logo,but it dsnt change the size that i gave in my js. before using ur code it was working properly

Comment: Did you manage to fix it @ZubairShah? My CSS code shouldn't alter how big the image is. That's strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192255/discussion-between-obed-marquez-parlapiano-and-zubair-shah).